# Delete all files already added to git repository based on .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I tried deleteting all files already added to git repository **exept** files whoe not ignored by .gitignore

my workaround was:

1. first i deleteted **all** files from the git repository,
2. then i added files whoe not ignored by .gitignore.

In this way, files were deleted, which were added (identical) immediately thereafter. This is of course sub-optimal, not maximal performant. Is there a better solution for this more elegant?

here my attempts to the finish:

```
Administrator@SL5 MINGW64 /g/global-IntelliSense-everywhere-Nightly-Build (master)
$ git rm -r --cached .
rm 'AHK Studio Download Page.url'
rm 'ActionLists/ActionListNameFilter.inc.ahk'
rm 'ActionLists/ApplicationFrameWindow/ActionListNameFilter.inc.ahk'

Administrator@SL5 MINGW64 /g/global-IntelliSense-everywhere-Nightly-Build (master)
$ git commit -m 'Delete all the stuff'

Administrator@SL5 MINGW64 /g/global-IntelliSense-everywhere-Nightly-Build (master)
$ git rm -r -f .

Administrator@SL5 MINGW64 /g/global-IntelliSense-everywhere-Nightly-Build (master)
$ git commit -m 'Delete all the stuff'
```

I guess if I had used `rm -r -f .` instead of `rm -r --cached .` I would have had the same effect.
After using `rm -r --cached .`, unfortunately there were still files in the repository that should not be there (regarding .gitignore).

`git rm -r -f .` and a commit+push deletes all from the git repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git ls-files` is the swiss-army knife of index-aware file listing.

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard -ci
```

will list every file that's cached aka staged aka indexed aka tracked and also marked to be ignored by auto-add, so you can

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard -ci | git update-index --force-remove --stdin
```

or to also delete from the worktree

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard -ciz | xargs  -r0 git rm -f
```

---

btw, I have `git config --global alias.ls 'ls-files --exclude-standard`, so for me the nuke-em is

```
git ls -ciz|xargs -r0 rm -f
```